# Get local Git repository path

Tags: git

I have setup my git project locally , so no remote servers like github, gitlab etc.
I want to get the local repository path because I want to use it with Jenkins CI/CD.

Following will not work for me which I have already tried since it is only for repositories that are setup on remote servers `git remote get-url origin`

How can I get local git repository path ?

Comment: `pwd` on linux?

Comment: `pwd` gives me `/var/www/html/<my project name>` is it valid to use current project path as a git repo url ?

Comment: If it is a Git repo yes, local paths can be remotes aswell

Comment: well that's the folder that you are working on, however I would suggest you to setup something like a Git server in the local env so that you have something like `localhost:XXXX/repo`

Comment: How can I setup a local git server ?

Comment: Careful: "path" means `$pwd`; "URL" is probably what you wanted here. Git can use a file path as if it were a `file://` URL, but only if your machine is also the Jenkins machine.

Comment: To setup a local git server you need an extra webserver (Apache/Nginx, locally) that forwards requests to the "git-http-backend" binary via (Fast)CGI. You can find guides for that on Google or here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already on the folder, you can use

```
pwd
```

for Linux, and

```
cd
```

for Windows

Answer (score 1):

You can just address local repositories using a file path to their directory:

```
git clone ../my-repo
git clone /path/to/home/my-repo
```

In the duplicated/cloned repo you will then see a "origin remote" with that path.

This of course only works for clients with access to your filesystem (so other processes on your machine, or NFS mounts).
Otherwise you could setup a small git-http-backend server.